# Authentication in Keycloak and authorization in service

Tags: authorization, keycloak

I have few microservices and traffic is routed through Spring Cloud API gateway. Want to have the API gateway to do the authentication and pass the bearer token to the service. The service will use the jwt passed through the TokenRelay filter from gateway and the extract the roles to authorize the call. In API gateway, I have the Securityfilterchain to validate the token by connecting to Keycloak as below:

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeExchange(
                    authorizeRequests -> {
                        try {
                            authorizeRequests
                                    .pathMatchers("/actuator/**")
                                    .permitAll()
                                    .pathMatchers("/metrics/**")
                                    .permitAll()
                                    .anyExchange()
                                    .authenticated()
                                    .and()
                                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                                    .jwt();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            log.error("Error in processing JWT" + e);
                        }
                    });
    return http.build();
```

In the service, I am permitting all calls without authentication and extracting the JWT as below:

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().permitAll())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(
                    httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer ->
                            httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.jwt(
                                    jwtConfigurer ->
                                            jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(
                                                    jwtAuthenticationConverter())));

    return http.build();
}
```

The above method extracts the role and stores in securitycontextholder. The roles are used in the method level authorization like hasRole at individual methods. The above flow is working fine.

Tried to find Keycloak events from Keycloak admin console which records token validation events but can't find any.

How to ensure the service is not connecting to Keycloak and validating the token again? Is there anyway to check the keycloak events to token validation calls?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't expect calls to Keycloak with resource servers using JWT decoders** (only resource servers configured with introspection call the resource server to validate each access token).

In your conf, `httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.jwt(...)` configures a JWT decoder => the tokens are validated on the resource server without calling Keycloak (only the public signing key is retrieved from the JWKS endpoint at startup).